# How do you connect the TCP client to the server and send to the server side? Getting errors and cannot successfully run code.

Tags: python, tcp, connect, tcpclient, tcpserver

I'm learning TCP and was trying out a client/server program. My server side is working, but on my client side, I can't connect successfully to the server side.

**Error Codes on my Client Side**

*First Error:*

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tcpclient.py", line 13, in 
    clientSocket.connect((serverName, serverPort))
TypeError: str, bytes or bytearray expected, not list

*Second Error:*

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tcpclient.py", line 34, in 
    clientSocket.send(clientSentence.encode(), serverAddress)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)

**Server Code**: This code runs successfully.

```
import sys
from socket import*

serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
serversys = sys.argv

if len(serversys) == 1: 
    serverPort = 9999
else:
    serverPort = serversys[1]
    serverPort = int(serverPort)

serverSocket.bind(('', serverPort)) 
serverSocket.listen(1)
print ("The server is ready to receive.")

while True:
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
    print ("Connection accepted from: ", addr)

    clientSentence = connectionSocket.recv(1024).decode()


    clientSentence, clientAddress = serverSockset.recv(1024)
    clientSentence.decode()
    connectionSocket.close()

    if clientSentence[0].decode() == 'U':
        serverSentence = clientSentence.upper()
        connectionSocket.send(serverSentence[1:].encode(), clientAddress)
        connectionSocket.close()
    elif clientSentence[0].decode() == 'L':
        serverSentence = clientSentence.lower()
        connectionSocket.send(serverSentence[1:].encode(), clientAddress)
        connectionSocket.close()
    elif clientSentence[0].decode() == 'I':
        serverSentence = clientSentence.title()          
        connectionSocket.send(serverSentence[1:].encode(), clientAddress)
        connectionSocket.close()
```

**Client**: This is where the two errors occur.

```
import sys
from socket import*

clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

clientsys = sys.argv
serverName = clientsys[1:]
serverPort = clientsys[2:]

clientSocket.connect((serverName, serverPort)) #First Error

serverPort = [int(serverPort) for serverPort in serverPort]
serverAddress = (serverName, serverPort)

sentenceChoice = input("Enter U for UPPERCASE SENTENCE, L for lowercase sentence, \nor I for Initial Caps Sentence: ")
sentence = input("Enter sentence: ")

clientSentence = sentenceChoice+sentence

clientSocket.send(clientSentence.encode(), serverAddress) #Second Error
serverSentence = clientSocket.recv(1024)
print('From Server: ', serverSentence.decode())
clientSocket.close()
```

Comment: Print out `clientsys[1:]` and see what it actually is!

Comment: @KlausD. It prints out: []

Comment: Doesn't look like a server name.

Comment: No it doesn't. I'll try setting the server name equal to local host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first error is caused by you using a list slice for the server name and port. Change to this:

```
serverName = clientsys[1]
serverPort = clientsys[2]
```

Your second error is because `socket.send()` doesn't accept the `serverAddress` tuple parameter (where you thinking of `socket.sendto()`? Either way, you can fix by simply removing the parameter:

```
clientSocket.send(clientSentence.encode())
```

Link to `socket.send` docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send

Comment: For the first error, I changed it but still receive the error: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Are you running your python command with args? For example if your script is named sock.py you should be running `python sock.py <serverName> <serverPort>`

Comment: So I fixed it and when running the client I enter "pthyon3 tcpclient.py localhost 9999" and it works, but then I receive the error from the server terminal window of a connection error:   File "tcpserver.py", line 29, in <module>
    clientSentence, clientAddress = serverSocket.recv(1024)
OSError: [Errno 57] Socket is not connected

Comment: @anonymous_s I think you need to remove this line `clientSentence, clientAddress = serverSocket.recv(1024)`. You should only be calling `.bind()`, `.listen()`, or `.accept()` for you server socket, in most cases. This socket only accepts connections and won't contain any data for you to read.

Answer (score 1):

are you sure it's supposed to be clientsys[2:] not clientsys[2] ?

Comment: When I take out the colon I receive an out of Index error. The same goes for client sys[1:].
File "tcpclient.py", line 11, in <module>
    serverPort = clientsys[2]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: have you supplied args when you run client.py ?

Comment: I don't think I have. When I run client sys[1:] it outputs: []

Answer (score 1):

The reason the error is occurring is that you are using list slicing to find the server and port from `sys.argv`:

```
clientsys[1:]
clientsys[2:]
```

The result of a list slicing operation is always a list:

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
>>>l[1:]
[2, 3]
>>>print(l[2:])
>>>[3]
```

Instead, use indexing:

```
serverName = clientsys[0]
serverPort = clientsys[1]
```

Comment: Should I remove sys.argv completely?